# Retrieve firestore-item with Dart-function in FlutterFlow

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I hope somebody can help me here, because I am trying to solve this already for hours now :)

I have a Firestore-collection "**hochzeiten**" with a timestamp-field "**datum_ablauf**".

The LowCode-plattform Flutterflow offers the possibility to use "Custom Functions" - and with this I want to get the value of the field "datum_ablauf" when handing over the DocumentReference to the function. So the template of the function (the part I can't really change) looks like this:

```
import 'dart:math' as math;

DateTime dateAblaufFromWeddingGEHTNED(DocumentReference currWedding) {
```

Well - I tried a lot and nothing worked, but here is my latest try:

```
  currWedding.get().then((snapshot) {
    DateTime datum = DateTime.parse(snapshot['datum_ablauf'].toDate().toString());
    return datum;
  });
```

Sadly I always get NUl, whatever I try.
Has somebody a hint for me?
Thanks!

Comment: I have the same problem... Did you find a solution ??

Comment: Yes, but a bit different: I started to put most of the business-logic (like getting the exp. date in this case) from the app (so FlutterFlow) onto the server. And for this I use the low-code-tool Rowy. Here I made a "Derivative field", that gets the date and writes it into the collection. So I can easily access it in FF.

Comment: i dug around the code that flutterflow generates and it seems that locally you can use the query"insert name of your collection"RecordOnce function which is contained in the backend.dart file. However, although it's imported in the boilerplate code of my function, i can't use this function in flutterflow. I just get an import error. Chatted to support about this i'll keep you posted